# How to edit android build.gradle in a managed expo project?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have a manged expo project, therefor I have no build.gradle file to edit.  I need to add the following lines to my build.gradle under the default config item:

```
{ missingDimensionStrategy 'store', 'play' }
```

I have found some information here in terms of changing the build.gradle file for expo projects, but am not sure how to add such a field.

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/#how-mods-work

I assume I have to make a mod and then import this into my app.json as a plugin?

What would this mod look like however?

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74942623/how-can-i-add-to-default-config-in-build-gradle-in-expo-managed-project

Comment: I found this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74942623/how-can-i-add-to-default-config-in-build-gradle-in-expo-managed-project, it can help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add to default config in build.gradle in expo managed project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74942623/how-can-i-add-to-default-config-in-build-gradle-in-expo-managed-project)