# How can I add to default config in build.gradle in expo managed project?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I need to add the following lines to the default config within my android build.gradle for my expo managed project

```
{ missingDimensionStrategy 'store', 'play' }
```

I believe I need to make a mod/plugin to add to this, but what would this look like?

Here is what I've tried to implement so far: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/#mod-plugins

using the withAppBuildGradle I believe is the best bet, but I'm not sure how to specifically add just the line in the android default config.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is still valid, this is how you can achieve it using Expo  modified flow.
Starting from Expo SDK 41 you can use [Config plugins](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/)

If you want to inject properties to android gradle this is how it can be achieved.

1. Create a new file in a root directory called `injectedAndroidConfig.js`

```js
const { withAppBuildGradle } = require('@expo/config-plugins');    

module.exports = function withAndroidStrategiesPlugin(config) {
    return withAppBuildGradle(config, (config) => {
        config.modResults.contents += `
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 31
                buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"
       
                defaultConfig {
                    targetSdkVersion 31
                    missingDimensionStrategy "store", "play"
                }
            }
        `;
        return config;
      });
    };
```

Here you can also set other properties you want (for example sdk version and so on)

2. You should update your app.json to use your created plugin

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "appName",
    [...]
    "plugins": ["./injectedAndroidConfig", "react-native-iap"]
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you would actually need a regex to replace the `android` object, since your current solution will just append to the file.